# UWP MapControl: Tilting MapIcons along with a MapControl

Tags: 3d, uwp, 2d, flat, uwp-maps

Is it possible to keep a `MapIcon` flat on a pitched `MapControl` in UWP?
When viewing the map in that default 2D-view everything is fine, but when I'm tilting the `MapControl` all `MapIcon`-elements stay in that 2D-view rather then tilting along with the map.

There are other elements (e.g. `MapPolygon` or `MapPolyline`) that behave exactly that way and are tilting along with the `MapControl`.

Is it possible to do that with a `MapIcon`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of MapIcon it to always remain screen-facing, even when viewing a tilted map. They are pinned to the map only at a single point.

As you noted, MapPolygons will lay flat on the terrain and tilt with the map. You could use a MapPolygon to draw an icon shape. If you have a raster bitmap you want to draw, you could use a tile layer to draw it.

The upcoming Windows release also has a new object - MapBillboard which might be useful.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks - MapBillboard seems interesting.